# Did the Buddha really have snails on his head?

Tags: the-buddha, history, enlightenment

For a long time I was told that when the Buddha touched the ground and became enlightened that his hair went up and formed a ball on his head and that that is what we see on the statues. But recently I heard a different story, that they are **snails**!

That is something that really made my day, but is it true? Are there only snails or did his hair also stand up?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think this topic has already been addressed...

Comment: @ChrisW: Ok, sure, I just didn't find it because I didn't find anything about snails in the potential duplicates... I guess I should have look further. But even after looking at the duplicate post I am still a little unclear on whether they were really snails or not? It seems to be still unknown. Unless I just didn't look closely enough?

Comment: [This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18292/254) references a blog entry by a [Theravada](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/theravada.html) monk to say "no snails". [Yinxu's answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/18476/254) is likely to be from a Mahayana perspective, and comments on the symbolism of "108".

Comment: @ChrisW: Ok, thanks! But when I get enlightened, I want snails!